# Web page text moves when clicked

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I was browsing the website 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm

in Internet Explorer 8 and when I click (or double click) many of the words they temporarily move.

I have developed a number of differnt webpages before and have never seen this, why is this happening? just curious if its an IE thing, poor coding, the coding platform used, etc... :)

FYI I am unable to use anything besides IE8 so I couldnt test browser compatablitity myself.

Comment: I genuinely sympathize with you if you can only use Internet Explorer.

Comment: if I download crome it is removed from the computer within a few hours, lol

Comment: I'm starting to get the impression it has something to do with "googleleads.g.doubleclick.net" the page uses...

Comment: @TheJavaBeast Can you be more specific about the repro steps? I work on the IE team, and am checking an instance of IE8, but I am not able to identify the issue. As for being tied down to IE 8, [Enterprise Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx) can liberate you ;)

Comment: for example if you double click "characters" (second line) in the first paragraph of the page it will move the text temporarily

Comment: it doesnt do this on other websites I visit so i doubt its directly related to IE, other then maybe the way it was coded for IE